# Can I pass additional arguments into a handler for PEAR_ERROR_CALLBACK?

Tags: php, error-handling, pear

I'm doing exception handling involving some PEAR code, and would like to (a) write my own error handler and (b) pass in more arguments than just the triggering event.  Or, something like this:

```
...
$pear_thing->setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_CALLBACK, 'my_handler', 'something else');
...

function my_handler($e, $other_arg) {
     ...
}
```

This code doesn't work (the second argument never gets passed to `my_handler`; is there any way around this?

Comment: if the something else is known at the time where the handler is being bound then you might be able to use an iefe

Comment: Is the `something else` something that will be known at the time the error handler is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the additional value is something that you will know at the time that the handler is set then you could do an IEFE (Immediately Executed Function Expression)

```
$handler = function ($otherArg) {
          return function($e) use ($otherArg){
              ....
          };
};
```

Then when you bind the function you can do this

```
$pear_thing->setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_CALLBACK,$handler('something else'));
```

In this case $handler is a function that returns a closure that closes around the argument passed to $handler.

Comment: Hmm -- it's not working for me; I'm getting syntax errors, first on the `var` keyword and then (inf `var` is removed) on the second `}`, presumably because I'm doing this in a function definition, not an object/method handler. BTW, the thing I'm trying to pass in to the handler is a variable defined earlier in the function.  Thus my attempt at the handler setup looks like `$pear_thing->setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_CALLBACK,$handler($the_variable));`

Comment: The var was me falling into javascript mode when working with closures that was an error.   the second } is necessary as it closes the outer function.  Worth noting that this solution will only work in php 5.3 or above.

Comment: (1) Figured as much :) (2) I see the matching going on with the second close-brace, but I've double-and triple-checked to make sure that my code matches yours, and php 5.4.15 is definitely throwing a syntax error at the second brace.  I know I'm the one asking for help here, but are you sure that the example is right?

Comment: What do you have in the inner closure? Comment it out and just try to `echo $otherArg;`

Comment: There was a syntax error... it needed a `;` after the inner function definition.